# PHP parse error - please point out the coding horror

Tags: php

`Class_view.php` contains the class definition as an associative array:

```
class View
{
    private $viewArray = array();   

    function getViewArray() {
        return $this->viewArray;
    }

    function addToViewArray($key, $value) {
        $this->view[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

In Index.php I have:

```
$view = new View();
$view->addToViewArray("title", "Projet JDelage");
// Much more code
include ("UI_Header.php");
```

And the code that causes the error is in `UI_Header.php`, around the "title" HTML tag:

```
<?php
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo htmlspecialchars($view->getViewArray()['title']);?>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css"     title="StyleSheetProjet" href="StyleSheetProjet.css" />
    </head>
```

I'm trying to get the value associated with the key `'title'` to show here.

The error I get is:

> Parse error: parse error in Header.php on line 7

Comment: *(related)* [Array dereferencing](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `$view->getViewArray()['title']`. PHP doesn't support this yet ([it will be included in the next PHP version](http://schlueters.de/blog/archives/138-Features-in-PHP-trunk-Array-dereferencing.html).) For now you need to create a temporary variable:

```
<?php $data = $view->getViewArray(); echo htmlspecialchars($data['title']); ?>
```

(But maybe you shouldn't put that in one line, it's hard to read. Maybe put a `$viewData = $view->getViewArray()` at the top of that script ;)

Another way (which is ***way*** more elegant) is to implement the [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface in the class, so you could directly use `$view['title']`. Or, alternatively, if you prefer using object access over array access you could implement the magic [`__get`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php) method (and `__set`, `__unset` and `__isset` methods, if you need them.)

Comment: Thank you.  The ArrayAccess interface is way over my head - I couldn't follow the manual's explanations.  Maybe in a few months...

Comment: @JDelage: Simply copy the four methods (the ones starting with `offset`) into your `View` class and replace all occurances of `$this->container` with `$this->viewArray`. Now you can use an instance of the class (`$view = new View;`) like an array. So to set the title you use `$view['title'] = 'Some nice title';` instead of `$view->addToViewArray('title', 'Some nice title')` and to get the title you use `echo $view['title'];` ;)

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, the array subscript syntax can only be used on a variable. You can't do `$view->getViewArray()['title']`. You need to assign the result of `$view->getViewArray()` to a variable, then do `$variable['title']`.